# Infinite sum of cosine function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity, trigonometric-series

What does the following expression equal to

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \cos(n\cdot\theta)=\text{?}$$

Comment: The limit of the partial sum seems to be indeterminate.

Comment: The [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) may interest you (if you are ready to accept distributions as an answer instead of a function).

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\cos(n\theta)=\Re\sum\limits_{n=1}^me^{in\theta}=\Re\frac{e^{i(m+1)\theta}-e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-1}.$$

This expression has no limit.